# What is the probability that A and B sit next to each other?

Tags: r, statistics, probability

We have a group of 20 people. We want to arrange them in a row in such way that A and B sit next to each other. I have to find the probability of that event in R language.

My solution is:

```
f1 <- function() {
  x <- sample(c(1:20), 20, replace = F)
  
  for (i in c(1:19)) {
    
    if (x[i] == 1 && x[i+1] == 2 
        || (x[i] == 2 && x[i + 1] == 1)) {
     TRUE
    }
  }
  
  F
  
}

prob_p <- function(Nrep) {
  rs <- replicate(Nrep, f1())
  sum(rs) / length(rs)
}

prob_p(100000)
```

I think I have some mistake in my solution, because when I run this code(I use RStudio), the result of the probability is 0.

Can you help me with figuring out what the problem is.
Any help or advice would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `return` your `result` from `f1`:

```
f1 <- function() {
  x <- sample(c(1:20), 20, replace = F)
  result <- FALSE
  for (i in c(1:19)) {
    
    if (x[i] == 1 && x[i+1] == 2 
        || (x[i] == 2 && x[i + 1] == 1)) {
      result <- TRUE
    } 
  }
  
  result # identical to return(result)
}

prob_p <- function(Nrep) {
  rs <- replicate(Nrep, f1())
  sum(rs) / length(rs)
}
prob_p(100000)
[1] 0.0988
```

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid a lot of indexing, looping, incrementing, accumulating, etc. if you use R's native facilities. Try this to see if person 1 and person 2 occurs next to each other or not.

```
 set.seed(345452L)
 run1trial <- function ()
   {# local vars used here to make the logic easy to see
    samp <- sample(1:20,20)
    a <- abs(which(samp==1)-which(samp==2)) 
    if ((a==1)) { return(1)}
    else {return(0)}
   }
 
 trials <- 100000
 out <- replicate(trials,run1trial())
 sum(out)/trials    

 # > sum(out)/trials    
 # [1] 0.09935
```

With R you rarely need to define your own loops as the various structures--vectors of length(n) in this case, but the same occurs with dataframes, lists, etc.--contain all the information necessary to do the indexing, incrementing, summing, etc. under the hood.

Note that it is possible to have 2 equivalent permutations. Given 10^18 permutations, this isn't likely much of a problem, however there is a package which can assure nonreplicated permutations: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppAlgos/vignettes/GeneralCombinatorics.html

Comment: I should add that of run1trial could be shortened to run1trial <- function ()
{samp <- sample(1:20,20)
ifelse(abs(which(samp==1)-which(samp==2))==1,1,0)
} But that makes it harder to see what's going on, of course.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run monte carlo simulations, you can try `mean` + `replicate` + `grepl` + `sample` like below

```
prob_p <- function(n) {
  v <- head(LETTERS,20)
  mean(replicate(n, grepl("AB|BA", paste0(sample(v), collapse = ""))))
}
```

such that

```
> prob_p(100000L)
[1] 0.10003
```

---

Mathematically, I guess the solution should be

```
> factorial(2)*factorial(19)/factorial(20)
[1] 0.1
```

Comment: Absolutely correct. That said, the .1 is also obvious in that there are 20 pairs possible at any set of positions but only 2 of them--c(1,2) and c(2,1)--are adjacent. However this seemed an exercise in bootstrapping notions.

Comment: One tenth of the total of all possible pairs of seats are the pair of interest. No pair can sit alone in one seat.

Comment: @JohnGarland I read it as the chairs were in a circle rather than a row - d'oh!